# RGB colour values are different from Powerpoint 2011 and 2016 - how do I fix please?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

It is critical that the RGB values are the same for a company brand palette but changing from 2011 to 2016 has caused a marked change that I cannot see how to fix. Can anyone help at all please?

Thank you

Comment: Not really enough info to go on. Is it a fully-calibrated workflow? Have your colour profiles changed in any way? Do you have before & after shots for us to see, to check we all see the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Old mac runs ppt 2011, new mac runs ppt 2016. All programs are set to work on Generic RGB which has worked perfectly for the past 4 years. New mac RGB values give incorrect readings when using colour calibrator on Generic RGB, but correct if changed to sRGB.  Visually they remain incorrect. We are replacing the old mac with new so continuing on 2011 is not a long term option. Is that better info - use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

John Korchok explains the likely cause and offers a few workaround in this thread on Microsoft Answers.  I don't feel comfortable quoting it here w/o his permission, but you can see the full thread here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macpowerpoint/setting-accurate-rgb-colors-in-os-x/4345a666-dab2-4148-a78c-f090464b2f38

Answer (score 0):

I have found that switching to HSL colours can fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not switched as the client dictates Generic RGB, but if all else fails, I will certainly try as an option. Thank you.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).